# Google Drive REST API returning different set of results to their Python library

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Using the [Files:list live API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) correctly returns all the files in the drive (there's 5 of them). The REST API URL (showing the parameters) is as follows:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22drive%22%2C%22driveId%22%3A%22[our-drive-id]%22%2C%22includeItemsFromAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22includeTeamDriveItems%22%3Atrue%2C%22q%22%3A%22trashed%20%3D%20false%20and%20mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.document%27%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22supportsTeamDrives%22%3Atrue%7D

Using the Python library returns only a subset of the files (3 of them). AFAICT, I'm passing in the same parameters.

The Python code is returning just the 3 files that were migrated from another storage solution. It's not finding the 2 files that were created directly in Google Drive.

Here's the Python code:

```py
def list_doc_ids_in_drive(self, drive_id: str):
    query = self._service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000,
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True,
        includeTeamDriveItems=True, supportsTeamDrives=True,
        corpora='drive',
        driveId=drive_id,
        q="trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'"
        )
    results = query.execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    return items
```

The Python code is using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` permission, which I think should be sufficient to find all 5 files. Has anyone else experienced an incomplete set of results when using the Python client library vs. the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

False alarm! Turns out the REST API and the Python client library are both returning the same data... once I'd deleted my Python pickle'd TOKEN file and re-authenticated to the Google Drive service...